# EAAccessory with car Bluetooth

Tags: ios, eaaccessory

I am developing an app which needs to detect if an iPhone is connected to a car. I would be using EAAccessory. My question is will EAAccessory detect this? Is the car Bluetooth(on which i am able to connect my iPhone and play music) MFI ?

Comment: Hi. Did you find an answer for this question?

Comment: Hi, I wanted the app to be able to work on any car and using any iPhone(i mean even using iPhone4). So could not use Bluetooth LE or EAAccessory. Had to use BluetoothManager instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Bluetooth LE, you don't need to join MFI. I've never used it, so I don't know how that works.

But if you use bluetooth 2.1, you need to join MFI first.
You can connect your device to bluetooth module in setting -->bluetooth. Then in your app,

```
accessoryList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] connectedAccessories]];
```

This should be able to tell you the connected Accessories.

Comment: But Bluetooth LE would only work on later iOS devices (iPhone 4S and iPhone5). This would not work on iPhone 4.

Comment: Right. But you can use bluetooth 2.1 which works for older iPhones.

Comment: @mn And you need to join MFI to use it.

Comment: The accessory is already paired. I connect and disconnect. Now when I power on the accessory again, will the accessory get connected automatically or I should do that? If so what APIs from EAAccessory Framework does that?

Comment: Is it possible to the setting-->Bluetooth-->connect pro-grammatically instead using EAAccessory Framework?